# Finding all specific strings in a file, and get the highest value out of the line

Tags: python, list, max, min

Ok, so I couldn't find an appropriate title so Ill explain as best I can.

I have a list made from the data of another file that is made out of names, lets take for example something like this one `list = ['AAA','BBBB','CCCC','DDDD']`. I want to search in another file all the elements of that list, and all the lines that contain them. Lets say my txt file looks like this.

```
    PIN |Direction |MaxUp     |MaxDn     |MinUp     |MinDn     |Net                                                                             
   AAA  |  IN      |0.46      |0.039     | -0.006   |0.009     | Top/AAA
   AAA  |  IN      |-0.015    |-0.020    |  0.016   |0.030     | Top1/AAA
   AAA  |  IN      |0.029     |0.019     | -0.006   |0.009     | Top2/AAA
   AAA  |  IN      |0.036     |0.029     | -0.006   |0.009     | Top3/AAA
```

So My code looks as follows:

```
for string in list:
    with open('Text.txt') as file:
         for lines in file:
              if string in lines:
                  #Get all lines
                  #Get the line with the highest maxup and Maxdn
```

The output of the process should show all the lines that have the string we are currently looking at so:

it should show all the 4 lines that hold AAA in this case, and it will then only get the with the highest MaxUp and MaxDn so output should be:

```
    PIN |Direction |MaxUp     |MaxDn                                                                               
   AAA  |  IN      |0.46      |0.039
```

I have a general Idea of what I should be doing but the process takes a long time since Im opening a file in a for loop seems kinda wrong to me.

Comment: Yes, opening and reading the same file 'N' times send wrong.  Swap the loops so that, for each line, you check the list of target strings.

Comment: Do you only care about it appearing in the PIN? or across the whole line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we should clean the data, this means removing all the `|` characters as well as the whitespace. Now we will have the data in a usable format, a python list. This means we can compare the values of each column quite easily.

So we begin the search for the lines by looping over each string in the list of search terms and then for each line of data we have, we check if the string is in the line and if it is, we check to see if it broke any records and then we record it. *Note: I have changed the name of list to li since list is a builtin in python*

```
li = ['AAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCC', 'DDDD']

lines = []
first = True
with open('Text.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if first:
            first = False
            continue
        lines.append([x.strip() for x in line.split('|')])

for string in li:
    print('Lines containing', string, ':')
    maxUp = None
    maxDn = None
    for line in lines:
        if string in line:
            if maxUp is None and maxDn is None:
                maxUp = line
                maxDn = line
            print(line)
            if line[2] >= maxUp[2]:
                maxUp = line
            if line[3] >= maxDn[2]:
                maxDn = line
    print()
    print('maxUp:', maxUp)
    print('maxDn:', maxDn)
    print()
```

With your data, I get the following result:

```
Lines containing AAA :
['AAA', 'IN', '0.46', '0.039', '-0.006', '0.009', 'Top/AAA']
['AAA', 'IN', '-0.015', '-0.020', '0.016', '0.030', 'Top1/AAA']
['AAA', 'IN', '0.029', '0.019', '-0.006', '0.009', 'Top2/AAA']
['AAA', 'IN', '0.036', '0.029', '-0.006', '0.009', 'Top3/AAA']

maxUp: ['AAA', 'IN', '0.46', '0.039', '-0.006', '0.009', 'Top/AAA']
maxDn: ['AAA', 'IN', '0.46', '0.039', '-0.006', '0.009', 'Top/AAA']

Lines containing BBBB :

maxUp: None
maxDn: None

Lines containing CCCC :

maxUp: None
maxDn: None

Lines containing DDDD :

maxUp: None
maxDn: None
```

Comment: I tried that and for some reason it will only look for the first string in the list. The other ones are not getting written in my output file. Also how would I go on getting the line with the highest Maxup and MaxDn?